# Free monad interpreter with side effect only

Tags: scala-cats

I need to write free monad interpreter which only perform effectfull actions but does not return any result. For free applicative I used interpreter with `MyAction ~> Const[Unit, ?]` signature and called it using `foldMap` function. However Const does not have monad instance. `Id` does not suit because it requires to return actual value (evaluate embedded language). Should I write my own monad instance, similar to Id but without underlying value or there is a more convient way to create interpreter which does not produce any values?

Comment: What do you mean by "not producing any value"? If any function is called, it has to return at some point. If function does not return a meaningful value, its declaration would be: `def myFunc(): Unit`.
So for your `F[A]`, result of your free program will be `F[Unit]`, do the job, but no value returned.

Comment: I guess question was ill formed. When using monad each next action will depend on result of the previous action. I.e. since bind has signature `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` there is no way to know `m b` without supplying `a` value. So answer should be "not possible by definition". With only one exception - when we using singletons as values (such as Unit). In this case each next action will not depend on `a` value since `a` will always be same.

Comment: To be correct, `Free` is all about sequencing actions, actions may or may not depend on previous values, but sequencing will be. Because in terms of `Free`, `Unit` returned by action would be also value. Can you elaborate on "exception - when we using singletons as values"? What else can be other than `Unit`?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "not producing any value"? Here is `Free` monad example with interpreters that return nothing, but do something.

```
import cats.{Id, ~>}
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp}
import cats.free.Free
import cats.free.Free.liftF


object Main extends IOApp {

  // define algebra
  sealed trait LaunchMissilesA[A]
  case class LaunchMissileType1(arg: Int) extends LaunchMissilesA[Unit]
  case class LaunchMissileType2(arg: String) extends LaunchMissilesA[Unit]

  // define Free type
  type LaunchMissiles[A] = Free[LaunchMissilesA, A]

  // smart constructors
  def launchMissileType1(arg: Int): LaunchMissiles[Unit] = liftF[LaunchMissilesA, Unit](LaunchMissileType1(arg))
  def launchMissileType2(arg: String): LaunchMissiles[Unit] = liftF[LaunchMissilesA, Unit](LaunchMissileType2(arg))

  // final program
  def launchVariousMissiles: LaunchMissiles[Unit] =
    for {
      _ <- launchMissileType1(1)
      _ <- launchMissileType2("str2")
    } yield ()

  // interpreter #1: IO
  def ioMissileLauncher: LaunchMissilesA ~> IO = new (LaunchMissilesA ~> IO) {
    override def apply[A](fa: LaunchMissilesA[A]): IO[A] = fa match {
      case LaunchMissileType1(arg) =>
        IO(println(s"[IO] launching Int missile of type 1: $arg").asInstanceOf[A])
      case LaunchMissileType2(arg) =>
        IO(println(s"[IO] launching String missile of type 2: $arg").asInstanceOf[A])
    }
  }

  // interpreter #2: Id
  def idMissileLauncher: LaunchMissilesA ~> Id = new (LaunchMissilesA ~> Id) {
    override def apply[A](fa: LaunchMissilesA[A]): Id[A] = fa match {
      case LaunchMissileType1(arg) =>
        println(s"[Id] launching Int missile of type 1: $arg").asInstanceOf[A]
      case LaunchMissileType2(arg) =>
        println(s"[Id] launching String missile of type 2: $arg").asInstanceOf[A]
    }
  }

  // end of the world
  override def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = for {
    _ <- launchVariousMissiles.foldMap(ioMissileLauncher)
    _ <- IO(launchVariousMissiles.foldMap(idMissileLauncher))
  } yield ExitCode(0)
}
```